# Chi-squared test and binomial distribution

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, p-value, binomial-distribution

In some circumstances the Chi-square test can be replaced by a test based on the binomial distribution. The common issue with using the binomial distribution is that it may quickly become tricky to calculate big factorials. However, one can easily use [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) in order to approximate such function. My question is: What test is it best to use then?

For example, I flip a coin and count the number of heads and the number of tails. I get 4519 heads and 4456 tails. Is my coin fair? Which test will give me the most trustful p.value, the chi-squared test or a test based on the binomial distribution (using Stirling approximation for ease of calculation)?

$$\chi ^2 = \frac{4456 - \frac{4456+4519}{2}}{4456+4519} + \frac{4519 - \frac{4456+4519}{2}}{4456+4519} $$

$$P(X < 4519) = \sum_{i=0}^{4519}{ {4456+4519} \choose {i} }0.5^{4456+4519}$$

Comment: In such large samples it makes almost no difference which you use. However, your chi-square statistic looks wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the Stirling approximation to compute the CDF (cumulative distribution function) of the binomial distribution. There is a relationship to the Beta distribution [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function). If $X \sim \mathcal{Binom}(n,p)$ then
$$ \DeclareMathOperator{\P}{\mathbb{P}}  
    \P(X \le k)=\mathcal{I}(n-k,k+1)
$$
so is expressed via the CDF of a Beta-distributed random variable (in mathematics, known as the *regularized incomplete beta function*.)