# Scaling the binomial random variable

Tags: distributions, binomial-distribution, beta-distribution, numerics

Why will someone even need a scale binomial random variable? If a distribution function can be given for $X/k$, where $k>1$, and $X$ is binomial, then probabilities for $x/k$ are deducible from the probabilities of $x$.  However, because the binomial coefficient in the expression of $x$ grows very fast, there is hope that computing probabilities associated with $x/k$ will solve the problem.

This question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1254069/164275 is on scaling of the binomial random variable. I disagree with it though--it is unnormalised.

Another solution is
$$
f(x/k)=\frac{1}{k}\frac{\Gamma((n/k) +1)}{\Gamma((n/k)-(x/k)+1)\Gamma((x/k)+1)}p^{x/k}(1-p)^{(n/k)-x/k}.
$$

which also has the normalisation problem. Can someone give an expression of the pmf of $X/k$?

Comment: Why do you need a pmf (probability mass function) for $X/k$? All probabilities associated with $X/k$ can be calculated from the pmf for $X$.

Comment: What do you mean by "disagree with it?" Your answer for the pmf makes zero here because it assigns positive probability to irrational values of $x$ (as just one example).

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen, true! I agree. But I want things the other way round. That is to directly calculate probabilities associated $X/k$. Why? Because computing probabilities w.r.t to $X$ involves large binomial coefficient computations that lead to overflows.

Comment: @AlexR.I assume you want to write makes zero sense. Well, $x/k$ might be irrational, however,  the gamma function is still defined. My interest is computing probabilities associated with $X/k$. The  reason is what I present in the comment before this one.

Comment: If youhave overflow problems then you are calculatinf the binomial coefficients the wrong way! There are muchmore effective ways to calculate binomial coefficients

Comment: In R for example, the binomial coefficient is inbuilt and is shipped with R, with routines written in C. It is hard to have better algorithms, you could also use the log gamma function for this. In essence, the actual computation of the binomial coefficient is not a problem. Let me add that my original problem involves many binomial coefficients and the ends up summing them.  This where the overflow is pronounced.

Comment: Please state your real problem, that is, which probabilities do you need? The cumulative distribution function of the binomial can be calculated via beta integrals, for instance, so no need of summing binomial coefficients!

Comment: Can you through more light on beta integrals? it sounds interesting!

Comment: What you need can be found here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function

Answer (score 3):

There is no need for a separate theory for scaled binomial distributions (although the terminology might be useful). Probabilities for the variable $X/k$ can be reformulated as probabilities for the binomial random variable $X$.

Your preoccupation with large factorials comes from using the wrong numerical methods.  Binomial probabilities can be calculated via the incomplete beta integral, see [Chi-squared test and binomial distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/103853/chi-squared-test-and-binomial-distribution).